# array size slice fallback using if else statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Says I want to limit a size of array, the condition is to always take the first item, we can do .slice but do I need if else statement for the slice method?

`result = arrays.length > 10 ? arrays.slice(0, 10) : arrays`

Above statement work but is the if else statement necessary? is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Sure,

`result = arrays.slice(0,10);`

If it's less than, or equal to, 10, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

> ...is there any better way to do it?

If speed is the concern a `while` loop is way faster:

```js
var i=0, l=arrays.length, result = [];
while (i<10 || i>l) { result[i] = arrays[i]; i++ }
```

Have made a jsperf -> **https://jsperf.com/slice-vs-while-with-length-check/1**

On my Chrome 63/Ubuntu `arrays.slice(0,10)` is **62**-**67**% slower than the `while` loop. This may seem like a pedantic detail, but if you slice a lot you can pretty much improve performance.